# A question about $\lim f(x)^{g(x）}=(\lim f(x))^{\lim g(x)}$

Tags: calculus

Does the following formula $$\lim f(x)^{g(x）}=(\lim f(x))^{\lim g(x)}$$

always hold?

If not, why?

And what about $\lim f(x)\cdot g(x)$? Is that the same as $\lim f(x)\cdot \lim g(x)$?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e \neq 1^\infty$

Comment: For questions like this, see "indeterminate forms" in your calculus textbook, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form

Comment: Could you clarify the questio you added  "...and what about$ \lim f(x)*g(x)$?Is that the same as $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$?"

Comment: I mean is that lim f(x)*g(x)=lim f(x)*lim g(x) always holds?

Comment: @ GEdgar thanks

Comment: @占俊涵 Yes, that's a simpler case and the equality holds always when $\lim f(x)=L_1\in R$ $\lim g(x)=L_2\in R$ since $L_1\cdot L_2$ is always well defined.

Answer (score 4):

I would say:  limit yourself to the case $f(x)>0$ and define $$f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp\big(g(x)\log f(x)\big).$$  Then you reduce to cases involving continuity of the product and the function $e^x$.

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: That method is fine and the best one to evaluate $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$ but in that case it seems to me that the OP is asking a slightly different thing that is when can we apply $\lim f(x)^{g(x）}=(\lim f(x))^{\lim g(x)}$ which, as you also noticed commenting my answer, can include cases with $f(x)\le 0$.

Comment: +1 This is way to go because the symbol $a^b$ is most easily handled by writing it as $\exp(b\log a) $ and the problem thus shifts to the limit of $g(x) \log f(x) $.