# Prove Power Rule for Limits: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = \left(\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\right)^{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta, formal-proofs

Suppose

- $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$
- $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = M$

I would like to prove

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^{g(x)} = \left(\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\right)^{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}=L^M$$

I thought this had probably been asked before, but the closest I can find is [Prove $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)^n = \left(\lim_{x \to a} f(x)\right)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83460/proof-of-power-rule-for-limits).

All limit law proofs I found on Google excluded this one. However it seems to be true, as it is listed on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties) (sadly without proof).

I imagine the proof is quite difficult, since $g$ can take on integer, rational, and irrational values in general, all of which would change the meaning of $f^g$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need conditions for this to work out, for example having zero/negative base and exponent wouldn't work out. Having said that, note that $\log(f(x)^{g(x)}) = g(x)\log f(x)$, so you can probably deduce any limit theorems as corollaries of the various theorems surrounding continuity (composition and product), and the continuity of the logarithm and exponential.

Comment: I don’t think this is that hard to prove, although that’s because I happened to be thinking about this question yesterday. What have you tried? The proof should go along these lines: For $\varepsilon$, no matter how small, there exists $x$ is close enough to $a$ such that $f(x)$ is close enough to $L$ and $g(x)$ is close enough to $M$ such that $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is close to $L^M$. I think you can use Binomial expansion or Bernoulli’s Inequality or something to fill in the details…

Comment: In fact, this question has been asked before. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739133/limit-rule-lim-fxgx?noredirect=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965942/a-question-about-lim-fxgx-lim-fx-lim-gx?noredirect=1). Found using Approach0 like [so](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%5E%7Bg%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%7D%24&p=1).